# click and scrolltop condition is not working in the same time

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with this operator. I want this *(actually very easy)*:

1. if **.scrollTop()** greater than or equal to 1480 **and** $(".promotion-video .play-button") has clicked
2. add a div block that have some images

BUTTT! **click condition is not working.** Why my dear developer bros? Please enlighten me.

```
<div class="promotion-video">
        <div
          class="row border-lines flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mx-0 overflow-hidden"
        >
          <img class="play-button" src="/src/assets/play-button.png" alt />
          <img class="text" src="/src/assets/promotion-video.png" alt />
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 1480 && $(".promotion-video .play-button").click()) {
            $(".promotion-video").html(`this is bullshit<div class="row border-lines flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mx-0 overflow-hidden">
            <img class="play-button" src="/src/assets/play-button.png" alt="" />
            <img class="text" src="/src/assets/promotion-video.png" alt="" />
          </div>`);
        } else {
            $(".promotion-video .play-button").on("click", change);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather add an event listener on the click `event` like this:

```js
$(".promotion-video .play-button").on("click", function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() >= 1480) {
            $(".promotion-video").html(`this is bullshit<div class="row border-lines flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mx-0 overflow-hidden">
            <img class="play-button" src="/src/assets/play-button.png" alt="" />
            <img class="text" src="/src/assets/promotion-video.png" alt="" />
          </div>`);
        } else {
            change();
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="promotion-video">
        <div
          class="row border-lines flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mx-0 overflow-hidden"
        >
          <img class="play-button" src="/src/assets/play-button.png" alt />
          <img class="text" src="/src/assets/promotion-video.png" alt />
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I've helped you find the cause of your problem. Now you may have others, if so, please post another question.

Comment: Do you want to permanently know if the scroll has reached a certain value? No, you want to know it **only** when you (as a user) have clicked on the button. I perfectly understand your problem. "It does not work" does not help solve any problem btw